# Does the main clause determine everything?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

If the clause is **If I disturbed you**:

1. **If I disturbed you**, I am sorry.
2. **If I disturbed you**, I would give you money.

Both of them use the past tense of disturb in the 'if-clause'

According to the subjunctive mood of past, 2 means '*As I don't disturb you, I will not give you money*' (assuming the opposite of the present fact or situation: past subjunctive).

According to the indicative mood, 1 means '*I disturbed you in the past and I am sorry now.*'

1 and 2 use same if clause using the same ***disturbed*** (literally the same if-clause) but has two different meanings due to different main clauses (*I am sorry* and *I would give you money*).

How do you know if a speaker says 'if-clause' with the intention of indicative or subjunctive. Do I have to wait for the main clause that follows the 'if-clause'?

If so, does the main clause determine the mood of the 'if clause'? (An important fact is that "a speaker opens his mouth and says exactly the same sound/thing").

Comment: Language is always contextual. One word can get as many nuances as the contexts it is used in. An "if clause" will become indicative or subjunctive only when situated in time by a main clause, or, if the main clause is omitted for some reason, by the surrounding context.

Comment: I'm afraid someone has been filling you with strange ideas. There is no "subjunctive mood of past" that determines what (2) means, nor are the meanings correct. As for how you know, you **listen**; different meanings are pronounced differently, with different intonations. If the sentence is written, then it's ambiguous, and you may have to guess, because the writer may have thought that it had a specific meaning because somebody told them some other rule about the subjunctive.There are a lot of them going around.

Comment: @fev and John Lawler, Thank you much for the advices. Understood well.

Comment: @JohnLawler I feel like this comes up several times a week here, but I don’t see a canonical duplicate either. Alas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Distinguish Real vs Unreal,
*not* Indicative vs Subjunctive

English conditional clauses like these should **not** be classed as
“subjunctive” vs “indicative” because English doesn’t really have “moods”
in any inflectional or morphological sense of that term.

Instead of moods,
[what English **does** have is
***modals***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/553000/2085), which with
one unique exception, are what we must use whenever something is other than
real. And your reals always come in exactly one of English’s two
inflectional tenses, either past or present.

[It is convenient to group conditionals by the nature of the verbs in their
consequent
clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/difference-between-if-present-will-infinitive-and-if-present-would/66143#66143),
which can therefore be exactly one of either real or unreal. All modals are by definition unreals.

1. If I disturbed<sup>*real (past)*</sup> you, I am<sup>*real (present)*</sup> sorry.
2. If I disturbed<sup>*real (past)*</sup> you, I would<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> give you money.

In both your two cases, the *if* parts use a real verb: *disturbed*. It is
not “subjunctive”.  The reality or lack of same is indeed indeterminate
until you get to the *then* part.  At that point, the first is real and the
second is unreal.

There are various other possibilities, including those with other reals and
other modals alike.  Remember that to make something unreal, you always
need a modal (or singular *were*).

4. If I disturb<sup>*real (present)*</sup> her, she always becomes<sup>*real (present)*</sup> upset.
5. If I disturbed<sup>*real (past)*</sup> her, she always became<sup>*real (past)*</sup> upset.
6. If I disturbed<sup>*real (past)*</sup> her, she would<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> always become upset.
7. If I can<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> disturb her, she may<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> wake up.
8. If I were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> to disturb her, she might<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> become upset.
9. If she need<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> not be disturbed, I will<sup>*unreal (modal)*</sup> leave her in peace.

---

Here’s a bit of background on this classification system. It works out much better than imagining things that English does not even have.

### 1. Reals

#### Real presents

These are actually “non-pasts”, but most people call them presents.

Except for *be*, these have a special inflection in only the third-person
singular alone and nowhere else.

- She disturbs me.
- I disturb them.
- I am disturbed.
- You have got to be kidding!
- He has disturbed you.
- It has been stopped.

#### Real pasts

These are inflect for the past tense, with all persons and numbers
the same except for *be*.

- I disturbed her.
- They disturbed me.
- He did disturb her.
- It had been stopped.
- She was disturbed.
- I was going to disturb her.
- They were disturbed.

### 2. Unreals

All unreals are modal unreals except sometimes for *be*.

#### Unreals via modals

These always use one of the standard English modals plus an uninflected
lexical verb following.

Additionally, there are three pairings of modals that for
backshifting purposes pair a “present/non-past” version coupled with a “past”
version: *will/would*, *shall/should*, and *may/might*.

- I can<sup>*modal*</sup> disturb her.
- Shall<sup>*modal*</sup> I disturb her?
- He could<sup>*modal*</sup> disturb her.
- You should<sup>*modal*</sup> not disturb her.
- I may<sup>*modal*</sup> disturb her.
- I will<sup>*modal*</sup> disturb her.
- I would<sup>*modal*</sup> disturb her.
- They might<sup>*modal*</sup> have disturbed.
- Dare<sup>*modal*</sup> he disturb you?
- One need<sup>*modal*</sup> not disturb them.
- Oughtn’t<sup>*modal*</sup> you not disturb her now?

#### The zero modal

One other modal verb that comes into play with these uninflected lexicals
is the so-called “zero-modal”. It isn’t an actual word, but we can construe its existence here because it modally marks the verb following in the very same way that a written-out modal does.

This type of modal is found only in special clause types.

- They are insisting that I <sup>*zero-modal*</sup> be there early.
- They were insisting that I <sup>*zero-modal*</sup> be there early.
- God <sup>*zero-modal*</sup> bless you.
- Long <sup>*zero-modal*</sup> live the king.
- <sup>*zero-modal*</sup> Have a nice day.

Being modals albeit of the zero variety, these are all still necessarily
unreals. That’s because all modals are always unreals.

#### Unreals via *were*

This occurs only with unreal *were*, normally the real plural past of *be*.
It is therefore morphologically distinct from the real past plural only when
it takes a singular subject.

- Imagine it were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> so.
- He acted as if she were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> here.
- If only she were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> here.
- I wish this were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> easier.
- She would have left us a note if she were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> ready to leave.
- Unless she were<sup>*unreal (were)*</sup> ready, she would leave us no note.

Comment: Some Korean TOEFL book teaches that 'zero-modal's father is 'should' and also teaches after 'unless' we should not use subjunctive mood(unreal according to you), for example, unless, but(that), save(that), except(that),and only(that).

Comment: @Brandon Nowadays *unless* seldom takes a bare infinitive as it once did in the not-too-distant past: *You must not break quarantine **unless it be** a matter of life and death.* Nonetheless, these are all just fine: *Don’t go unless she calls. Don’t go unless she happens to call. Don’t go unless she should call. Don’t go unless she should happen to call. He didn’t go unless she called. He wouldn’t go unless she called. He wouldn’t go unless she were to call. He wouldn’t go unless she happened to call. He wouldn’t have gone unless she had called.* Do feel free to call those whatever you will.

Comment: Far too long an explanation. You risk losing your reader's attention. Incidentally, the conditional _if_ adjuncts are not clauses but PPs.