# What is the number of the verb in "We require that"?

Tags: verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood, infinitive-constructions, modality, mandative-subjunctive

I am writing a paper in which I need an object to satisfy a condition.  (I can give the specifics here, but it seems to be irrelevant to the question.)  The object is singular, so I originally wrote (using the "academic we"):

1. We require that the object satisfies the condition.

However, (1) sounds weird to me; for some reason, this:

2. We require that the object satisfy the condition.

sounds better.

(The reason may have something to do with the subjunctive mood, but, every time I refer to the subjunctive mood, I get something wrong—for example, I don't know if this sentence is even properly described as being in the subjunctive mood—so I won't try it outside of parentheses.)

Which one, if either, is to be preferred?

Comment: The subjunctive in English has mostly gone away, and it is left in two almost completely unrelated grammatical constructions. This one is the "mandative subjunctive" or "present subjunctive", where the form of the verb is the same as the infinitive. The other one is the "irrealis subjunctive" or "past subjunctive", where the form of the verb is the same as the past tense. Calling them both the subjunctive is very confusing, but maybe not as confusing as renaming them (as has been done by some grammarians).

Comment: Untensed verbs do not inflect for number, so the question does not make sense at face value.

Comment: @PeterShor, [thanks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572626/what-is-the-number-of-the-verb-in-we-require-that#comment1426773_572626)!  So is it the case that a reference to the subjunctive does not belong here?

Comment: @tchrist, [thanks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572626/what-is-the-number-of-the-verb-in-we-require-that#comment1426776_572626)!  Is it just that I should not have referred to the number of the verb in the title (in which case, please feel free to edit the title to something more appropriate), or is there some deeper flaw in the question that would, say, prevent my using either construction?

Comment: No, if you google "present subjunctive" or "mandative subjunctive", you should find references to this construction. If you just google "subjunctive", you will also find references to the "irrealis subjunctive", which is completely unconnected with this construction in 21st-century English (even though historically they were both two instances of a much more widely used subjunctive mood).

Comment: We require the object satisfy the condition. We recommend the object satisfy the condition. Funny thing though, here, I would make it passive: The object is required to satisfy the condition,

Comment: @LSpice When we use the base form of the verb (or bare infinitive if you prefer) in these cases, we ***“modally mark”*** the clause as “not-real” just as much as we do when we use a modal verb like *should* or *must* in front of it. These never have number. It's usually in the deontic mode of permissions and commands (hence “mandative”) but like any modal use can also be in the epistemic mode in other circumstances. I talk about a little bit about this so-called ["zero-modal" in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/556183/2085).

Comment: @PeterShor, [thanks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572626/what-is-the-number-of-the-verb-in-we-require-that#comment1426780_572626) again for the clarification and, especially, further pointers to terminology!

Comment: @tchrist, [thanks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572626/what-is-the-number-of-the-verb-in-we-require-that#comment1426788_572626) again for the reference!  I will have a look.

Comment: @Lambie: that's only because the subject is the academic *we*, and thus can (and maybe should) be omitted.

Comment: The mandative subjunctive (or subjunctive mandative) is not some kind of "replacement" for anything. It is the correct name for the traditional subjunctive construction, i.e. the one headed by a plain form verb, as in "It is vital [that I be kept informed]". And we don't call the 'irrealis' the 'irrealis subjunctive'. Irrealis is a mood form, unlike the subjunctive mandative, which is a type of clause construction. This is an important distinction. Note that English does not have a subjunctive mood.